# Finding the image size using JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load the image with the minimum size of 2KB. I am unable to use any server technology here. Is it possible to know the size of the image using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272441/anyway-to-get-image-file-size-using-javascriptor-jquery-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using html5 stuff (if you can't use server-side).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

or though Flash app since almost everyone have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have load this image via AJAX and then use content-lenght property. Check this out.